# Why is drawRoundRectComplex() not documented in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, drawrect

In studying actionscript 3's graphics class, I've come across the undocumented `drawRoundRectComplex()` method.  It's a variant of `drawRoundRect()` but with 8 parameters, the final four being the diameter of each corner (x, y, width, height, top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right).

```
//example
var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
sp.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
sp.graphics.drawRoundRectComplex(0, 0, 200, 150, 110, 50, 0, 10);
addChild(sp);
```

this seems to be a pretty useful method, so i'm just curious if anyone knows of any reasons why adobe chose not to document it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's documented in the `mx.utils.GraphicUtils` class.

[Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/GraphicsUtil.html?filter_flex=4).

Comment: there it is.  strange that it doesn't show up in blue in frame or actionscripts for flash cs4.  i guess it's under-documented rather than undocumented.

Comment: is mx.utils.GraphicUtils a legacy class?  if so would that make drawRoundRectComplex old also?  is there something newer?

Comment: Formally I think everything in the mx.* package is Flex, or at least used to be. Offhand I suspect that the undocumented part is that Graphics implements what used to be a flex-only routine?