# Draw bottom rounded corner

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, air

How can i draw a shape, that is **only rounded** at it's bottom, without using [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) libraries?

[image]

```
  var _myShape:Shape = new Shape();
      _myShape.graphics.lineStyle(4,0x000000,1,true,....);
      _myShape.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,50,50,10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use Flex libraries (as you've commented on Glenn's answer) and if you're only concerned will fills, you could employ a masking technique on your sprites.

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
sprite.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 300, 200, 100, 100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();

var spriteMask:Shape = new Shape();
spriteMask.graphics.beginFill(0);
spriteMask.graphics.drawRect(0, sprite.height / 2, sprite.width, sprite.height / 2);
spriteMask.graphics.endFill();

sprite.mask = spriteMask;
sprite.addChild(spriteMask);

addChild(sprite);
```

including strokes is a little trickier, but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

See this page: [Why is drawRoundRectComplex() not documented in ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474392/actionscript-why-is-drawroundrectcomplex-not-documented)

You need "drawRoundRectComplex"

**EDIT:** If you can't the Flex SDK, your only other "real" drawing option is to use a combination of `lineTo` and `curveTo`. The easiest way to do this is to copy the code from the `GraphicsUtil` class in the Flex SDK. I'm not clear if it's considered open-source or not, so I'm not going to post it here.

Comment: is there maybe another way, without using flex libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a stroke by using a `GlowFilter`, although it will be more expensive than a true stroke.

You also don't need a mask -- just draw two boxes.

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(s);

s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
s.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,50,50,10);
s.graphics.endFill();

s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,20);
s.graphics.endFill();

s.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x0, 4, 8,8, 40)];
```

Comment: GlowFilter will suffice for thin strokes, but it's not a solution for thick strokes as it becomes noticeably blurry or for strokes that must be clean and sharp.  i wish the Graphics class had a proper stroke method - lineStyle() is just simply laughable.  additionally, there's also the option to create 2 shapes for more control, but set the blendMode on the inside shape to BlendMode.ERASE.